# Run FFMPEG-Kit command with commas and single quotes

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG-Kit for iOS BUT this issue applies to all releases of FFMPEG-Kit... within my command I run `[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[withOpacitySet]` but it does not work, if I run the command without that it runs fine...

Is it the commas? The quotation marks?

Comment: Welcome! What "does not work"? Do you get an error? Does it not generate the output you expect? (Also, it looks like you may have posted this question to more than one SE site. That is generally frowned upon.)

Comment: Hello @MichaelLiebman the error is not detailed as it generates from the library, mainly, I have come to the safe conclusion that the library will not take that syntax since my terminal does accept it. I did post this same question on StackOverflow, I did not know it was frowned upon, I just wanted to reach more people. If it is against the TOS I have no problem on taking it down. The error is simply `Error creating video...`... nice... lol. I know the issue is in the line of FFMPEG posted though, as if removed, it runs successfully.

Comment: Multiple posts don't violate any policy, they are just considered bad etiquette since the answers don't share across the sites. Your question ends up helping less people in the end. Sorry I don't have any answers on your problem since the library, as you said, really everything clear. ;)